# Intel App Framework scrolling not working

Tags: scroll, mobile-application, appframework

I am working on an app using Intel App Framework and XDK, and I am having a lot of trouble getting scrolling to work properly outside of the emulator. I dont yet have an Apple developer license, so I can only test on iOS using App Preview

The first problem is with full page panels. On Android builds and Android/iOS emulator, they scroll fine, but they dont scroll at all on iOS. HTML for panel:

```
<div class="upage panel" id="uib_page_info" data-header="af-header-info" data-footer="none">
<div class="upage-outer">

    <header class="container-group inner-element uib_w_2" data-uib="app_framework/header" data-ver="0" id="af-header-info">
        <a id="backButton" href="javascript:;" class="button" >Back</a>
        <h1>Info</h1>
        <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered"></div>
        <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left"></div>
        <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right"></div>
    </header>

    <div id="uib_page_infosub" class="upage-content ">
        <div style="width:100%; ">
            <!-- text content here, long enough to need scrolling -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The second problem is with a div that occupies only part of the viewport, with the rest of the page not scrolling. In the emulator it works fine, and I got it to scroll once on Android, but have since been unable to, even on the same build. In the emulator, a scrollbar appears on the side and the mouse wheel works. HTML for panel:

```
<div class="upage panel" id="uib_page_events" data-header="af-header-events" data-footer="none" data-load="DoCalendarLoad">
<div class="upage-outer" style="height:100%">

    <header class="container-group inner-element uib_w_3" data-uib="app_framework/header" data-ver="0" id="af-header-events">
        <a id="backButton" href="javascript:;" class="button" >Back</a>
        <h1>Event Calendar</h1>
        <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered"></div>
        <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left"></div>
        <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right"></div>
    </header>

    <div id="uib_page_eventssub" class="upage-content " style="width:100%; height:100%; background:#FFFF00">
        <div id="eventsContent" style="width:100%; position:absolute; top:0px;"> 
            <input type="text" id="example" style="position:absolute;top:-40px;height:40px;width:100%;" gldp-id="calendarDiv"/>
            <div class="ratioCalendar" id="ratioOuter" style=" position:absolute; top:0px; width:100%; background:#FF0000">
                <div class="ratio_content" id="ratioInner" style="background:#00FF00" gldp-el="calendarDiv"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ac-container" id="listDiv" style="position:absolute; width:100%; bottom:0px; background:#EFE7D0; margin:0px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden" scrolling="yes" >

                <!-- several of the following, formatted as http://cssdeck.com/labs/5p3sqfwi -->
                <div class="ac-container">
                    <div>
                        <input id="ac-2" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" /> 
                        <label for="ac-2">
                            <span class="event_date">05.07.2013</span> Title 
                        </label>
                        <article>
                            <!-- content -->
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong in both of these instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work a lot with the same framework too. I like it but it is picky. Usually when things stops working on different platforms it is caused by load order. I had a massive problem with Android.

Check the docs for the correct order of js, css and start functions. That is what fixed my problems.

edit:
Sorry, just read the second part of your message. This is the exact same problem i had. No sizing, no scrolling, but other things worked. Check out the order of it.
And try

```
 $.feat.nativeTouchScroll=true;
```

I found this little function after 4 days of internet searches. It unlocks what is says.

Comment: It turned out to be the script order and a missing script. I am using jquery as well, and I wasnt including jq.appframework.js. 

The correct order is jquery, jq.appframework.js, appframework.ui